# How to check if we have more pages in GA4 using JAVA

Tags: java, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-java-client

I am reading the `GA4` info according to the code sample provided here in [Google Developers Documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/quickstart-client-libraries).
I do not know how to check if there are more pages? looking at the result's size I guess I am missing something. Supposing "credentialsJsonPath" contains info for credentials, my code is something like this:

```
            Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(credentialsJsonPath).getParent());

            GoogleCredentials credentials =
                    GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream(credentialsJsonPath));

            BetaAnalyticsDataSettings betaAnalyticsDataSettings =
                    BetaAnalyticsDataSettings.newBuilder()
                    .setCredentialsProvider(FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials))
                    .build();    

            try (BetaAnalyticsDataClient analyticsData =
                    BetaAnalyticsDataClient.create(betaAnalyticsDataSettings)) {

                RunReportRequest request =
                        RunReportRequest.newBuilder()
                        .setProperty("properties/" + "my propertyId")
                        .addDateRanges(DateRange.newBuilder().setStartDate("2022-10-02").setEndDate("2022-11-02"))

                        .addDimensions(Dimension.newBuilder().setName("fullPageUrl")) 
                        .addDimensions(Dimension.newBuilder().setName("pagePath"))  
                        .addDimensions(Dimension.newBuilder().setName("eventName"))  
                        .addDimensions(Dimension.newBuilder().setName("date")) 
                        .addDimensions(Dimension.newBuilder().setName("customEvent:dim1"))
                        .addDimensions(Dimension.newBuilder().setName("customEvent:dim2"))
                        .addDimensions(Dimension.newBuilder().setName("customEvent:dim3"))
                         

                        .addMetrics(Metric.newBuilder().setName("activeUsers"))  
                        .addMetrics(Metric.newBuilder().setName("engagementRate"))
                        .addMetrics(Metric.newBuilder().setName("sessions"))
                        .addMetrics(Metric.newBuilder().setName("eventCount"))  
                        .addMetrics(Metric.newBuilder().setName("userEngagementDuration"))
                        .addMetrics(Metric.newBuilder().setName("averageSessionDuration"))
                        .addMetrics(Metric.newBuilder().setName("screenPageViews"))  
                        .addMetrics(Metric.newBuilder().setName("totalUsers"))
                        .addMetrics(Metric.newBuilder().setName("eventCountPerUser"))
                        .addMetrics(Metric.newBuilder().setName("bounceRate"))                          
                        

                        .build();
                RunReportResponse response = analyticsData.runReport(request);

                if(response.getRowsList().size()>0) {
                    for (Row row : response.getRowsList()) {
                      // Here I read the desired info 

                    }
                }
```

Is there any method that can check something like response.getNextPageToken() or something similar?

Comment: check this [pagination](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/basics#pagination) if you cant figure it out let me know and i will see if i cant come up with a example

Comment: Thank you @DalmTo, it sounds strange to me to repeat the request 2 times using once 0 to 100000 offset and once again from 100k to 100k more. and what if there are more than 200k reports? how many times should I repeat it?

Comment: yup.  just keep looping until you are done if you really need all those rows.   Look on the bright side with the reporting api its 10k rows.  This will be much faster with Ga4 

Comment: btw if you get it working can you remember to answer your own question.   to help others in the future.

Comment: since I cannot see all the custom events, I see in debug view, I am not sure if my java code has problem or the department that has managed the GTM is missing something. Before asking I wanted to make sure about my code :D

Comment: remember the name has to be correct customEvent:test_event   If you have access to the account test it here https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/ga4/query-explorer/